How to physically bind an object

I have a static object and an object with a cloth modifier. How do I link the selected sides so that the cloth doesn't fall off completely, but the selected side is snapped to the parent?
.blend

Create a vertex group where you want the cloth object to stick to the other one, select this vertex group in the Cloth panel > Shape > Pin Group?

@moonboots It only sees groups of vertices of the “fabric object” itself, and not a static object
